# Second AngularJS directive not loading from html attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have this directive which avoids an input to be marked as `$pristine`:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('blocks.noDirtyCheck', [])
      .directive('noDirtyCheck', function() {
        // Interacting with input elements having this directive won't cause the
        // form to be marked dirty.
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          //require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$pristine = false;
          }
        };
      });
})();
```

and this other one, which defines a custom widget, `<workflow-input>`:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.widgets')
    .directive('workflowInput', workflowInput)
    .controller('WorkflowInputController', WorkflowInputController);

  /* @ngInject */
  function workflowInput() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        selectedWorkflow: '=ngModel'
      },
      controller: WorkflowInputController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/client/app/widgets/workflowInput.html'
    };
  }
...
})();
```

I want to use it as this:

```
<workflow-input ng-model="vm.asset.workflows" no-dirty-check></workflow-input>
```

I understand that the `noDirtyCheck` directive is incomplete, since it's not being applied directly on the actual `<input>` and it needs to be fixed, but that's not the issue at hand, the problem is that the `noDirtyCheck` directive is never being called. I put a breakpoint on the `workflowInput` controller and I can see the directive is not listed in the element's `controllerDirectives` in `nodeLinkFn` (in angular's codebase). There's only `ngModel` and `workflowInput` there.

Anyone knows why this might be happening? Thank you

Comment: It should work so there must be something else going on. Can you provide a [MCVE] demonstrating the issue? Are you certain that you've injected your `blocks.noDirtyCheck` module?

Comment: you're right, I forgot injecting it. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot injecting the module into the application. Thank you @Lex